# solid color border for rounded element

Tags: css, border

I want to have round left border on an element which has `border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px` (top-left, bottom-left). But with normal `border-left: 10px solid black`, it doesn't look really round (like circle I mean). Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcnr81h1/).

It seems browser first add solid border, then round whole element, including solid border.
But I need vice versa and a round solid border.

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly. Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gcnr81h1/1/)? This makes use of inset box shadow instead of border.

Comment: Explain what you want to achieve. Try to give an image of your goal please, we don't understand what's wrong

Comment: Ok, it's what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/gcnr81h1/2/ I did it with `overflow: hidden`, but better solutions welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Can can use a box-shadow to get a more rounded border.

http://codepen.io/Spaceman/pen/ejDJK

```
#rounded {
    background: lightblue;
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
box-shadow: -5px 0px 1px 0px #000000;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```